# Last Clicked Radio button ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have table which consists of multiple rows and each row consists of Radio button in the first column as follows:

```html
<table class="table table-condensed span8" id="AllocationTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th title="Entity to Allocate" style="width: 30%">Entity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.EntityAllocations)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="@item.ID" class="EntityRadioSelect" value="@item.ID" onclick="EntitySelect(this)" disabled="disabled" >
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to capture the Ids of the last clicked radio button
I have tried something like this

```
function EntitySelect(select) {
    if ($(select).parent().data("lastClicked")){
        alert($(select).parent().data("lastClicked"));
    }
    $(select).parent().data("lastClicked", select.id);
}
```

But I am getting the wrong value as it is giving me current value and sometime other values which is not accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clicked='';
var preClicked='';
$("#AllocationTable").on("click",".EntityRadioSelect",function(){
    preClicked=clicked;
    clicked=$(this).attr("id");
});
```

remove onclick="EntitySelect(this)"

Comment: it will give the this elements id i.e the current id not the previous one

Comment: I updated, you may try it. You can get current and previous one

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
function EntitySelect(select) {
    var parent=$(select).parents('#AllocationTable');
    if (parent.data("lastClicked")){
        alert(parent.data("lastClicked"));
    }
    parent.data("lastClicked", select.id); 
}
```

Comment: You might as well replace that whole `if` block with `alert(select.id)`.

Comment: Sorry i am getting the current clicked radio button id not the previous one the same result as before

Comment: ok, i think we looked wrong parent, i changed answer please try again